# How to count how many time a sequence appears in a give string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, iteration, sequence

I am trying to count how many time a sequence appears in a given string.

```
def count_seqence(str, seq):
    count = 0
    if seq in str:
        count += 1
    return count
print(count_seqence("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog","he"))
```

But this only runs once and does not loop, how can i loop and count how many times appears, because i know looping would be for each char and not a seq, this is making me confusing.

Comment: `mystr.count('he')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `count` on your string, it will return the number of time it found your parameter value `seq`

```
def count_seqence(str, seq):
    return str.count(seq)

print count_seqence("kjdsflsdnf lskmfldsknffsdlkfnsldkmf", "ds")
```

Output

```
2
```

Comment: its so embarrassing that is only a single line and i have three hours, doing attempts with if and elif statements, thanks buddy

Comment: The other answer is more complete including the case when the sequence overlaps.

Comment: @JonathanGagne: can you provide a reference to this convention? Furthermore some complicated solutions tend to be more efficient. For example a slicing solution to count overlapping instances is indeed easy to understand, but scales *O(m n)* whereas the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm is harder to understand, but scales *O(m + n)*.

Comment: @JonathanGagne: where in the question is it **specific**about overlapping counts? :)

Comment: But yes, I want more since for now, you still did not share a canoncial answer. Somehow you did not only give a pars-pro-toto answer, but also a pars-pro-toto link :) Perhaps I should have been more specific, can you provide a *canonical* link that specifies that the shortest answer is the best?

Answer (score 6):

Well since you use an `if`, and not in a loop, that means that either the condition is `True`, and thus you increment `count`, or it is `False` in which case you do not execute the body.

If you want to count numbers, you will need some "looping" mechanism. This does not have to be explicit, for example `in` hides a loop as well. But this only results in `True` or `False`.

## Non-overlapping (`count_seqence('aaaa', 'aa')` is `2`)

For non-overlapping counts, we can use `str.count`:

```
def count_seqence(text, seq):
    return text.count(seq)
```

in which case defining a specific function of course is rather useless. Note that the above will only count *non-overlapping* matches. For example when you count `'aa'` in `'aaaa'` you will get `2`, not `3`.

## Overlapping (`count_seqence('aaaa', 'aa')` is `3`)

For overlapping, we will need to perform a `str.find`, and update the "search window" until we no longer find a match, like:

```
def count_seqence(text, seq):
    cnt = 0
    idx = text.find(seq)
    while idx >= 0:
        cnt += 1
        idx = text.find(seq, idx+1)
    return cnt
```

We thus have an `idx` that stores the index where the new match occurs, and each time that `idx` is larger or equal to `0` (we found a match), we increment `cnt`, and change `idx` to the *next* match.

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.count` method. Check [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org) for that.

Example:

```
x = "wip wip I'm a sheep wip"
print(x.count("wip"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use count on your string, it will return the number of time it found your parameter value seq

def count_seqence(str, seq):
    return str.count(seq)

print count_seqence("kjdsflsdnf